# Bluetooth settings is not opening

Tags: bluetooth

The bluetooth settings is not opening on my Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS when I click in the Blutooth Settings in the menu bar.

No messages are shown in the UI. Please let me know how to fix this annoying issue.

Comment: Did it work before?

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this issue by reinstalling the `unity-control-center`.

```
sudo apt-get remove unity-control-center
sudo apt-get install unity-control-center
```